# Trying to figure out how to set off an event when the enter key is pressed in a TextBox

Tags: .net, f#, textbox

The code I'm playing with is:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing

let tehform = new Form(Text = "STOP!", Width = 200, Height = 200)
let awe = new TextBox(Left = 1, Top = 30, Width = 100)
let stuff _ _ = MessageBox.Show(awe.Text) |> ignore
let handler = new EventHandler(stuff)
let yeah = new Button(Text = "", Left = 20, Top = 60, Width = 80)
yeah.Click.AddHandler(handler)
let ms = new MenuStrip()
let file = new ToolStripDropDownButton("File")
let ddi = file.DropDownItems.Add("Hi")
ddi.Click.AddHandler(handler) |> ignore
ms.Items.Add(file) |> ignore
let dc c = (c :> Control)
tehform.Controls.AddRange([| dc yeah; dc ms; dc awe |])
```

I thought, by looking at the library, I could use awe.OnEnter.AddHandler(handler) but that didn't work either. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You know you play too much Halo when... 

You call your Form "tehForm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnEnter fires when the TextBox gets focus.  Use the OnKeyDown event and check the Keys property of the event args.

[Here's the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(VS.80).aspx).